# How i can define schema for array using jsonloader?

Tags: arrays, json, apache-pig, elephantbird

I am using elephantbird project to load a json file to pig.
But i am not sure how i can define the schema at load. Did not find a description about the same.

data:

```
{"id":22522,"name":"Product1","colors":["Red","Blue"],"sizes":["S","M"]}
{"id":22523,"name":"Product2","colors":["White","Blue"],"sizes":["M"]}
```

code:

```
feed = LOAD '$INPUT' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader() AS products_json;

extracted_products = FOREACH feed GENERATE
    products_json#'id' AS id,
    products_json#'name' AS name,
    products_json#'colors' AS colors,
    products_json#'sizes' AS sizes;

describe extracted_products;
```

result:

```
extracted_products: {id: chararray,name: bytearray,colors: bytearray,sizes: bytearray}
```

how i can give the correct schema to them (int,string,array,array) and how can i flatten array elements into rows?

thanks in advance

Comment: i have tried (chararray)products_json#'id' and that worked, but its not too sophisticated and not sure how i should cast an array.

Comment: Pig doesn't support array kind of datatype. One option could be you can store it as chararray.

Answer (score 0):

to convert json array to tuple:

```
feed = LOAD '$INPUT' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader() AS products_json;

extracted_products = FOREACH feed GENERATE
products_json#'id' AS id:chararray,
products_json#'name' AS name:chararray,
products_json#'colors' AS colors:{t:(i:chararray)},
products_json#'sizes' AS sizes:{t:(i:chararray)};
```

to flatten a tuple

```
flattened = foreach extracted_products generate id,flatten(colors);
```